# Highstock compare How to compare current data point with the previous data point

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I am using this compare example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare.
This example is great. It shows the difference between the beginning data (index 0) and the current data. For example, I have data like:

```
[
   [147893849384,20] (+0%)
   [147893849385,40] (+200%)
   [147893849386,400] (+2000%)
   [147893849386,10] (-50%)
]
```

I want to modify compare the previous data not the beginning data.

```
[
   [147893849384,20] (+0%)
   [147893849385,40] (+200%)
   [147893849386,400] (+1000%)
   [147893849386,100] (-75%)
]
```

How Could I do that? Please Help~

Thank you.

Comment: Comparing does not work as in your first example. It calculates the difference between the first and the current point in the relation to the first point. (curr - first) / first https://jsfiddle.net/kbcdkmok/ Your example does curr / first. So if you want the comparing to work as in Highstock but it should take the previous point, instead the first, then you need to do the calculation on your own. In this case the calculation provided by @Aliester are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so judging from the data provided it is only comparing the second index of each array.  So you could do something like this:

```js
var data = [
  [147893849384,20],
  [147893849385,40],
  [147893849386,400],
  [147893849386,10]
];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  // skip first item
  if(i === 0) { 
    continue;
  }
  
  let prevDataPoint = data[i - 1][1];
  let currentDataPoint = data[i][1];
  
  // Multiply by 100 to get value as percentage.
  let percentageDifference = ((currentDataPoint - prevDataPoint)/prevDataPoint) * 100;
  
  console.log(i + " Percentage Difference: " + percentageDifference + "%");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Aliester but this is not what I want to do. Thanks again~

Comment: @TimLee  Would you mind pointing out where my answer strayed from what you do want to do?